# Parsing XML into Java object

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, domparser

I am trying to determine the best way to parse the XML response I get from a webservice call into a Java object.
Using JAXB seems to be the easiest way but every example I get for this requires that you have a template Java class which will be the Java type the XML is converted into.
My xml is as below

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <entry_list version="1.0">
      <entry id="main[1]"> <hw highlight="yes" hindex="1">main</hw> <sound><wav>main0001.wav</wav></sound> <pr>ˈmeɪn</pr> <fl>adjective</fl> <lb>always used before a noun</lb> <def><dt>:most important :<sx>chief</sx> <sx>principal</sx> <vi>the <it>main</it> idea/point</vi> <vi>the <it>main</it> goal/purpose</vi> <vi>Speed is the <it>main</it> advantage of this approach.</vi> <vi>The company's <it>main</it> office is located in New York.</vi> <vi>the novel's <it>main</it> character</vi> <vi>driving down the <it>main</it> road/highway</vi> <vi>the <it>main</it> gate/entrance</vi> <vi>This dish can be served as a <phrase>main course</phrase> or appetizer.</vi> <vi>And now for the <phrase>main event</phrase> of the evening!</vi></dt></def> <uro><ure>main*ly</ure> <fl>adverb</fl> <utxt><vi>The reviews have been <it>mainly</it> [=<it>mostly</it>] positive.</vi> <vi>a plant found <it>mainly</it> [=<it>chiefly</it>] in coastal regions</vi> <vi>I don't like the plan, <it>mainly</it> because I think it's too expensive.</vi> <vi>The problems have been <it>mainly</it> minor ones. [=most of the problems have been minor ones]</vi> <vi>They depend <it>mainly</it> on/upon fish for food.</vi></utxt></uro></entry>
      <entry id="main[2]"> <hw hindex="2">main</hw> <altpr>ˈmeɪn</altpr> <fl>noun</fl> <in><il>plural</il> <if>mains</if></in> <def><sn>1</sn> <sgram>count</sgram> <dt>:the largest pipe in a system of connected pipes <vi>a gas <it>main</it></vi> <vi>a water <it>main</it></vi></dt> <sn>2</sn> <bnote>the mains</bnote> <ssl>Brit</ssl> <sn>a</sn> <dt>:the system of pipes or wires for electricity, gas, or water <vi>My radio runs either off batteries or off <it>the mains</it>.</vi> <un>often used as <it>mains</it> before another noun <vi>We haven't had any <it>mains</it> water/electricity since the storm.</vi></un></dt> <sn>b</sn> <dt>:the place where electricity, gas, or water enters a building or room <vi>Turn off the water at <it>the mains</it>.</vi></dt></def> <dro><dre>in the main</dre> <def><dt>:in general <un>used to say that a statement is true in most cases or at most times <vi>The workers are <it>in the main</it> very capable. [=most of the workers are very capable]</vi> <vi>The weather has <it>in the main</it> been quite good. [=has been quite good most of the time]</vi></un></dt></def></dro></entry>
      <entry id="main clause"> <hw>main clause</hw> <fl>noun</fl> <in><il>plural</il> <if>⁓ clauses</if></in> <def><gram>count</gram> <sl>grammar</sl> <dt>:a clause that could be used by itself as a simple sentence but that is part of a larger sentence <ca>called also <cat>independent clause</cat></ca> <dx>compare <dxt>coordinate clause</dxt> <dxt>subordinate clause</dxt></dx></dt></def></entry>
      <entry id="main drag"> <hw>main drag</hw> <fl>noun</fl> <in><il>plural</il> <if>⁓ drags</if></in> <def><gram>count</gram> <sl>US</sl> <sl>informal</sl> <dt>:the main street in a town or city <vi>A carload of teenagers were cruising down the <it>main drag</it>.</vi></dt></def></entry>
      <entry id="main line"> <hw>main line</hw> <fl>noun</fl> <in><il>plural</il> <if>⁓ lines</if></in> <def><gram>count</gram> <dt>:an important highway or railroad line</dt></def></entry>
      <entry id="main man"> <hw>main man</hw> <fl>noun</fl> <in><il>plural</il> <if>⁓ men</if></in> <def><gram>count</gram> <sl>US</sl> <sl>informal</sl> <sn>1</sn> <dt>:someone's best male friend <vi>He's still her <it>main man</it>.</vi></dt> <sn>2</sn> <dt>:the most important or admired man in a group <vi>The team has many good players, but he is clearly the <it>main man</it>.</vi></dt></def></entry>
      <entry id="main squeeze"> <hw>main squeeze</hw> <fl>noun</fl> <in><il>plural</il> <if>⁓ squeezes</if></in> <def><gram>count</gram> <sl>chiefly US slang</sl> <dt>:someone's main girlfriend, boyfriend, or lover <vi>She's my <it>main squeeze</it>.</vi></dt></def></entry>
      <entry id="main street"> <hw>main street</hw> <fl>noun</fl> <in><il>plural</il> <if>⁓ streets</if></in> <def><sn>1</sn> <sgram>count</sgram> <dt>:the most important street of a U.S. town where there are many stores, banks, etc. <un>often used as a name <vi>The restaurant is at 257 <it>Main Street</it>.</vi></un></dt> <sn>2</sn> <bnote>Main Street</bnote> <sgram>noncount</sgram> <ssl>US</ssl> <dt><un>used to refer to middle-class people in the U.S. who have traditional beliefs and values <vi>What does <it>Main Street</it> think of this policy?</vi></un></dt></def></entry>
      <entry id="water main"> <hw>water main</hw> <fl>noun</fl> <in><il>plural</il> <if>⁓ mains</if></in> <def><gram>count</gram> <dt>:a large underground pipe that carries water <vi>The <it>water main</it> burst/broke and flooded the street.</vi></dt></def></entry>
  </entry_list>
```

My question is ,  do I have to define the Java object that this will be converted into?  What I am afraid of if this is the case is what happens if data is added or removed from the XML response as it exists at the moment.
I have also tried loading the XML into a DOM and walking thropugh it that way but againi I am wondered what will happen if an element is added or removed?
I only want certain child nodes if their parent node is a certain value so any pointers as to the easiest way to do it would be welcome.

Comment: Can you be more specific as what you want to accomplish as a result so I can probly submit more curated answer

Comment: @vtd-xml-author  I want to extract all data in the <hw> tags i.e. <hw>XXX</hw> if its sibling <fl> node contains a certain value. I can walk through the XML ok ( with SAX parser ) and get the data I require but I would like to do it the "proper" way,  as I may not be the one to be maintaining this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to work with a XML is to serialize it to an object.
You can do it with JAXB, here is an tutorial: [mykong](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/)
Just define how objects should look like.
Here is an example:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "entry_list")
public class EntryList {

    @XmlElement(name = "entry")
    private List<Entry> entities;

    public List<Entry> getEntities() {
        return entities;
    }
    public void setLastName(List<Entry> entities) {
        this.entities = entities;
    }
}

public class Entry {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

    @XmlElement
    private Sound sound

    etc
    ...

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Sound getSound() {
        return sound;
    }
    public void setSound(Sound sound) {
        this.sound = sound;
    }
}
```

Every element that got a child element have to be a class and if it repeats multiple times like *entry* or *vi* it should be a list.

Comment: Thanks for other suggestions guys but this seems to be by far the most straight forward way to do this and maintainability is my priority for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Frequently called a POJO, yes, it's a good idea (maybe even necessary) to have one. It defines how your data should be represented as an object. If data is missing, the fields of the Java object will be null. Therefore, you should define your Java object to be the maximum cover of all possible attributes.

There may be some libraries that will put additional attributes into a Hashmap (at least I know Jackson can do that for JSON, not sure about XML)

The only alternative would be to parse it yourself manually in a way that you can guarantee the capture of all elements, such as depth first traversal of the nodes

Comment: With the given XML do I need to create the entire Java POJO class heirarchy.  By that I mean the XML is a list of Entry objects,  and within each Entry object are sub structures. Do I need to create classes for each?

Comment: I think you only need one class per different structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **SAX** parser. The beauty of this method, apart from being fast and low-memory, is that you get to ignore everything you don't want or need - then you don't care if those section change. You just catch the tags you want as they pass through.

For example, if you were only interested in the "main clause" tag, your handler would look something like:

```
public class MyHandler extends org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler {

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if ("entry".equalsIgnoreCase(localName) &&
                "main clause".equalsIgnoreCase(attributes.getValue("id"))) {
            // Set a member variable flag
            // So we know how to process nested tags
        }
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if ("entry".equalsIgnoreCase(localName)) {
            // Unset the flag
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when you have to deal with very complex XML document its probably easier to:

1. Transform it into more simple form
2. Marshal it into object that you can work with

I.e. lets say you've got a very complex XML:

```
<XML>
   <SomeElement>
       <MoreElements>
           <EvenMoreElements>text</EvenMoreElements>
       </MoreElements>
   </SomeElement>
</XML>
```

Step number 1: simplify it using XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <SimpleForm><xsl:value-of select="XML/SomeElement/MoreElements/EvenMoreElements/text()"/></SimpleForm>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Step 2. Marshal your own SimpleForm XML into java object

That way you loose coupling between external schema and your internal logic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think JAXB is the best solution here... The best solution is based on XPath, which allows you to simplify the coding without sacrificing code maintainability... as you can see below in the code, your navigation is just one XPATH expression, and the entire program is about 10+ lines code that uses XPath and VTD-XML, BTW your xml example posted above is not well-formed...

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
public class extractExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws VTDException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        if(!vg.parseFile("d:\\xml\\sample.xml", false)){
            return;
        }
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        ap.selectXPath("/entry_list/entry/hw[following-sibling::fl='value']/text()");
        int i=0;
        while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
            System.out.println(" hw value are "+vn.toNormalizedString(i));
        }
    }

}
```